# prompt() with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, ietester

I am having a hard time figuring out a solution for my problem. Here's a code snippet:

```
var ans = prompt("Mot de passe", '');
if (ans != '' && ans != null)
   __doPostBack('__Page', ans);
else
   window.location = "../Erreurs/NotAuthorized.aspx";
```

This code works really great with Internet Explorer 9. But my client is exclusively working with Internet Explorer 8 so I tested it with ieTester in IE8. But the problem is that **the prompt doesn't show** and it automatically redirect because the input had an empty string ('').

So how do I fix this to work with Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: Does it matter if you add something to the second parameter?

Comment: If I add (for example) 'test' in the second parameter, the prompt doesn't show up neither. Is is a known bug with ieTester or it just doesn't work with a real IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a security thing specific to IE- 8 for sure, I don't have other versions to test. Calling `prompt()` produces a warning about a scripted window asking for information. I can click to allow and after refreshing the page, the prompt box appears as expected.

If you are going to insist on using `prompt()`, you will probably have to stipulate that security settings on the target machines are configured to allow it.

Answer (score 8):

IE has an setting in Internet Options to allow or deny `prompt()`.

[image: IE prompt setting]
<sub>(source: [adamhaskell.net](http://adamhaskell.net/img/ie-prompt.png))</sub>

By default in IE8, this setting is off. Consequently, calls to `prompt()` are ignored and `""` is returned by them.

You shouldn't use `prompt()` anyway. Use a form.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft developer website tells us that "prompt()" is deprecated and now normally blocked for security reasons:
"By default, this method is blocked by the information bar in the Internet zone. This helps prevent malicious sites from initiating spoofing attacks. "

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536673.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From this report it looks like it's a known bug in IETester?

http://www.my-debugbar.com/forum/t294-Javascript-Alerts.html

Comment: I think the problem is the prompt isn't even showing, not the following if statement.

Comment: Yes, just saw the thread... But I can't get it working with IE7 or 6 neither.