# Prompt does not allow me to enter text in internet explorer phtml

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to updated the text in a prompt in phtml file and it is not working in internet explorer 11 but it is working fine in Firefox. Any help??

```
$.prompt("Enter text", $td.text().trim(), function(name){...}
```

Comment: may this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197147/prompt-with-internet-explorer-8

Comment: check answers of users like **Niet the Dark Absol** and  **lincolnk**

Comment: I've applied all these solutions but none of them did work

Comment: so you build a form? I highly doubt it.

Comment: It is working in any browser other than IE! Any help